# Use Ruby to get URL parameters

Tags: html, ruby

I am currently using the script

```
 <?php $name = $_GET ["id"]; ?>
```

to pull the parameter from a URL like `www.example.com?id=john` and then using

```
 <?php echo $name ?>
```

when I need the variable in the code.

I now need to use Ruby instead of PHP to accomplish this task. Are there any comparable methods in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: If you set up your Rails application properly, they would be passed in via class instance variables set in the controller. The controller gets them from the `params` hash. For a Rails app, you don't just replace php with Ruby, if that's what you're attempting. See [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

Comment: I am making a web app that opens in a separate window and is not contained in the rails framework, I just access it in the public folder. The website manager does not want me using PHP however due to possible security vulnerabilities and wants me to replicate what the php does with GET using a Ruby script. I am not familiar with ruby scripts though.

Comment: Your problem said "Rails" which is a complete web application framework with classes, etc, defined to take care of all this. You should remove "rails" from the reference (subject and tags) if you're not using Rails and are just using Ruby.

Comment: Okay done. I am integrating this app into a website that uses ruby on rails but I have developed my app outside of the framework and just need a script that can bridge the data through url parameters.

Comment: I found something related [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), maybe this helps? Specifically, `decode_www_form`.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has all the functionality needed, but it's a steep learning curve, so maybe [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) would be better for what you need. In particular, Sinatra, like Rails, makes it easy to get at the parameters in a URL. See Sinatra's ["Routes" documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes) if you want to go that way.

Here's code to extract the parameters from a URL using Ruby and its bundled URI class:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.com?id=john')
uri.query # => "id=john"
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)] # => {"id"=>"john"}
```

You can assign the result of the last line to a variable, then use it to access any of the parameter's values via its name:

```
params = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)]
params['id'] # => "john"
```